# How to add calendar event while app is in foreground/background/killed without opening calendar app?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, calendar, background-service

I'm working on a flutter app where I'm receiving notification from firebase in the foreground as well as the background. There is a flag of notification where i want to add event in phone/mobile default calendar without opening that calendar in apps both state foreground and background. It's some how working with `manage_calendar_events` package in the foreground state but not working in background state. I already give permission of the calendar in manifest file to read and write calendar and also allow in app. I already tried with `add_2_calendar` but it's opening the calendar APK.
So my question is how to add event in the calendar without opening calendar and Flutter app in both foreground and background state of APK on notification trigger.
Note: I need this while receiving notification not clicking on it.